# how to update selected value of the dropdown list to the database

Tags: python, django

I got values of dropdown list which is expense.id and expense_type. In database I look for expense object which has id==expense.id sent by ajax in order to update its type (expense_type). So I need to send both expense.id and expense.type to sever using ajax. I dont know how to perform in jQuery as well as html. Below is my code I got error which is "Not Found: /polls/17/project_detail/ajax/update_form/"

```
<form  action="/ajax/update_form/" method="POST" id="selection-form">
{% csrf_token  %}

<select id="select_dropdown">
{% for expense in expenses %}
    {% if project.id and expense.city %}
        <option value="{{expense.id}}" selected="selected">{{expense.expense_type}}</option>
    {% else %}
        <option value="{{expense.id}}">{{expense.expense_type}}</option>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
<td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>

</form>
```

=====js====

```
        $('#selection-form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("form_submitted");
        create_post();
        });

        function create_post(){
                console.log("update fucntion is working!");
                var value = $("#select_dropdown").find(":selected").val();
                var text = $("#select_dropdown option:selected").text();
                $.ajax({
                        //url: "{% url 'update_form' %}",
                        url: "ajax/update_form/",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {
                                "value": value,
                                "text": text,
                                //"pro_expense": pro_expense,
                                //"id": valueSelected,
                                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                        },
                        //dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data){
                                console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function(error_data){
                                console.log("error")
                                console.log(error_data)
                        }

                });
                return false;
        };
```

====views.py=====

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_form(request):
        if request.method == "POST" and request.is_ajax():
                value = request.POST.get('value')
                text = request.POST.get('text')
                expense = Expense.objects.get(pk = value)
                expense.expense_type = text
                expense.save()

        return HttpResponse({"result": "success"}, content_type="application/json")
```

===urls.py===

```
url(r'^(?P<project_id>[0-9]+)/project_detail/$', views.project_detail, name='project_detail'),
url(r'^ajax/update_form/$', views.update_form, name = 'update_form'),
```

error is "Not Found: /polls/17/project_detail/ajax/update_form/". please help. Any help will be highly appreciated!!